# src, href and import is not working

Tags: html, css, web

a. src - image is not loading in firefox when i used "img src". loading in chrome and IE.

b. href - it is not working while i am trying to add css file externally.

mystyle.css

```
h1, h2, h3 {
color: #36C;
font-weight: normal;
letter-spacing: .4em;
margin-bottom: 1em;
text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

css.htm

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="C:\Divakar_Repository\html_learning\mystyle. css">
</head>
<h1>CHEcking the css style</h1>
```

but it is displaying the output as "CHEcking the css style" in black color.
actuallly the output should be as "checking the css style" in blue color.

c. import - it is not working.

import.htm

```
<head>
@import "C:\Divakar_Repository\html_learning\mystyle.c ss";
</head>
<h1> CHEking the css file </h1>
```

But it is returning the output as below.

@import "C:\Divakar_Repository\html_learning\mystyle.c ss";
CHEking the css file

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you....

Comment: "ystyle.c ss";" why is there a space between c and ss?

Comment: There's a space in <link type="text/css" href="C:\Divakar_Repository\html_learning\mystyle. css"> aswell.

Comment: i just copied the code from my notepad++. dont know why it is showing like this here. dont find space in my document.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @import where you use your CSS, not just in the head element, and with a properly format.

You can @import css files in the `style` element or in your css file this way:

```
@import url(mystye.css);
```

Your syntax is more Sass/less related, not CSS.

And also take care about file names.

Also before opening a `h1` tag you should **open a `body` tag first**.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths when referencing your stylesheets:

`<link type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">`

The link is relative the position of the document you link from in your directory structure, so make sure the path is correct. Also make sure there are no spaces in weird places.

The `@import` function only works from within a stylsheet, so either you use it in a .css file or wrap it in `<style>` tags:

```
<style>
@import url(mystyle.css);
</style>
```

Onelast note, in the `<head>` section, it is required to have a `<title>` element. You cannot skip this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.

it worked if i have @import between style element.

and link element is worked after i add the property rel="stylesheet".

but i have some questions.

back slash wont work except IE? because if i point to file with path like c:\ it is not working in firefox and chrome